# To function to string, search and replace function, execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, eval

I am trying to do something crazy, I have a JSON object of all sorts of rules for my website. I have a system set up where I can write pseudo code and then it turns it into actual code. I have this working perfectly for strings, however now I need to be able to pass functions, and replace the pseudo code inside of functions, then execute the functions.

I think I am on the right track, however when I turn a function to a string it only turns the output of the functions into a string.

Here's my JSON (part of it)

```
customValidation: {
    //compare: "(<!this!> && <!PrimeTimeDiscount!> == 200) || (<!PrimeTimeDiscount!> == 100)",

    compare: function(){

            return new Validator()["date"]("<!this!>", 50);                                             
    },
    overrideDefault: true
}
```

The commented out "compare" is how I use this system for regular strings.

And below is how I handle turning `"<!this!>"` and `"<!*!>"` into values from the JSON object. It is basically the same code twice, but the one below I have started modifying for when a function is detected.

```
if(typeof customValidationRule != "function")
{
    var string = customValidationRule.match(/<!(.*?)!>/g);
    var customValidationTerms = new Array();

    var execCustomValidationRule = customValidationRule;

    $.each(string, function(i, v){

        var customValidationTerm = v.replace(/<!/g, "").replace(/!>/g, "");
            customValidationTerms.push(customValidationTerm);
    });

    $.each(customValidationTerms, function(i, v){

        var RegEx = new RegExp("<!"+v+"!>", "ig");

        if(v == "this")
        {
            var newData = value ? value : "''"; 
        }
        else
        {
            var newData = FormData[parentKey][TermNames[v]] ? FormData[parentKey][TermNames[v]] : "''";
        }

        newData = dataType == "currency" ? cleanVar(cleanCurrency(newData)) : newData;
        newData = newData ? newData : "''";

        execCustomValidationRule = execCustomValidationRule.replace(RegEx, newData);

    });

}
else
{
    var customValidationRuleString = customValidationRule().toString();

    var string = customValidationRuleString.match(/<!(.*?)!>/g);
    var customValidationTerms = new Array();

    var execCustomValidationRule = customValidationRuleString;

    $.each(string, function(i, v){

        var customValidationTerm = v.replace(/<!/g, "").replace(/!>/g, "");
            customValidationTerms.push(customValidationTerm);
    });

    $.each(customValidationTerms, function(i, v){

        var RegEx = new RegExp("<!"+v+"!>", "ig");

        if(v == "this")
        {
            var newData = value ? value : "''"; 
        }
        else
        {
            var newData = FormData[parentKey][TermNames[v]] ? FormData[parentKey][TermNames[v]] : "''";
        }

        newData = dataType == "currency" ? cleanVar(cleanCurrency(newData)) : newData;

        newData = newData ? newData : "''";

        execCustomValidationRule = execCustomValidationRule.replace(RegEx, newData);

    });

    var backToFunction =  eval('(' + execCustomValidationRule + ')');

    //validation = customValidationRule();
}

validation = eval(execCustomValidationRule);
```

Comment: Why not write your functions so that your dependencies (`this` and `PrimeTimeDiscount`) are passed in as arguments? This does away with the whole _pseudo-code_ idea. Unless you are writing an actual DSL I wouldn't recommend your current approach.

Comment: Also, you're using `RegExp`s to find your tokens. Since your tokens are static (not regular) you can use `.indexOf` or just `.replace` directly.

Comment: I know what you're saying, it doesn't make sense given the code above. However the nature of the site, and how data is passed, stored, and executed makes it difficult, almost impossible I think to do it like that. I think the way that I am doing it works very well for what it is expected to do, however I need to be able to pass in more complex "CustomValidation" rules now, so I am trying to modify my system to do this.